# Find a specific value, first appearance and display the value

Tags: excel, vba

I just need some help that seems like a simple problem.

In my excel file, I want to search for the first appearance of value in a column and produce where it occurs at. In my column A, I have a listing of numbers (the x-axis) and in column F, I have a series of data. I want to find the very first appearance of a value in column F that is greater than 7.5 and place it's relative column A value in another cell. Both columns A and F run from cells 1 to 4000.

If possible any help with a VBA function or just a simple input function would be great help!

Comment: Have you tried `HLOOKUP` / `VLOOKUP` functions ?

Comment: How would I use those exactly? I am kind of a novice at Excel

Comment: An other way to do it is to use `MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($F1:$F10>7.5,0),0)`, which will give you the number (N) of the row where the first value > 7.5 is located. Your data is then in the cell `"A" & N`. Use `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(,))` to get its value.

Comment: The ColumnF values are  not in any particular order, they are mostly in ascending but not perfectly in order

Comment: @AaronMelcer It should not matter with the formula I gave you

Answer (score 0):

With quite a lot of guessing, this may suit:

> =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(7.5,F:F,1)+1,1)

*Edit* I guessed wrong.

Answer (score -1):

So would this work?

```
=IF(F1 > 7.5,A1)
```

paste this into your H cell. if F is less then 7.5 it will return False

Comment: You should have added a comment, not an answer (since your post does not answer the question) :p

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear enough, it is kind of early. But if the first value over 7.5 appears in F22, then I would like to place the A22 value in another cell, such as H1. The A value is what I'm really looking for because it is my x-axis value (a specific time) and the F column is just where all the data is being read from.